# Amazon SQS Priority Queue

Tags: ruby, amazon-sqs

Is it possible to create a priority queue using the Amazon simple queuing service?

Initially I couldn't find anything on the subject and this is why I create two queues. A general queue and a priority queue. I am enqueuing messages to this queue according the rule I've defined but confusion arises while dequeuing messages.

How do I do a long poll on the queues such that my combination of queues behave like a single priority queue?

Answer (score 6):

I think you're on the right track by creating two queues - A normal queue and a priority queue.

You don't necessarily need a long poll in this case. Since messages in the priority queue take precedence over messages in the normal queue, you could follow an approach like this:

1. Poll priority queue till there are no more messages.
2. Poll normal queue and repeat step 1 after every message in the normal queue.

Comment: Poll is a blocking call. If there are no messages in the queue, I would be blocked on the priority queue and never move to the normal queue.

Comment: That would depend on what API you're using to poll the queue. The documentation here mentions you can specify the wait time. A short wait time here should be the equivalent of a simple check to see if there are messages - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html

Comment: Ya, don't use long polling and it won't block at all.

Comment: shoryuken will rotate through all the queues, checking the higher priority queue more based on the weight.  If you want to keep checking the high priority queue and only move on to lower priority after it is empty, that would require patching/forking it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Shoryuken](http://github.com/phstc/shoryuken/) and set a higher weight to configure the priority:

```
queues:
  - [high_priority_queue, 5]
  - [low_priority_queue, 1]
```