# Priority Queue implementation for SQS Spring and Java

Tags: java, amazon-sqs, spring-jms

Looks like Ruby has [shoryuken](https://github.com/phstc/shoryuken/), what does Java have for this, there is this answer to SO for Ruby, [Amazon SQS Priority Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22494357/amazon-sqs-priority-queue), I am yet to find any example or way to do this with JMS and Spring, which is weird in itself. It feels like all consumption is pushed into the infrastructure, that I have maybe 5 consumers on high priority and 1 consumer on low priority, but I can't have 6 consumers alternating in where they take their work from.

Comment: Why are you linking to an Android java file for Wifi?

Comment: Whoops wrong link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I answered to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59277342/control-consumption-of-multiple-jms-queues/59277497#59277497); the `JmsListener` is a message-driven approach, similar to JEE MDBs; you can use a `JmsTemplate` instead to have complete control over fetching messages.